# How Can I Call GetAsyncKeyState() in UWP DirectX/XAML App?

Tags: c++, keyboard, directx, uwp-xaml

I have some code I'm porting from a working WinJS/UWP app to a DirectX/XAML variant, but I can't get my hands on the keyboard state.

Controller is not a problem, that works just fine via XInputGetState().
My problem is just the keyboard.

Existing code is:

```
Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow^ win =
    Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();      
if (win)
{   
    // misc. calls to win->GetAsyncKeyState()
}
XInputGetState(activeController, &inputState);
```

But that fails because Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread() returns null.

If I try this, I can get a win object:

```
Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow^ win =
    Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow;

if (win)
{   
    // misc. calls to win->GetAsyncKeyState()
}
XInputGetState(activeController, &inputState);
```

But then the window (a swapChainPanel) doesn't render.

In fact if I take out the 'if' part altogether on that one, it still doesn't render as though the action of me having the termerity to get a reference to the CoreWindow means it goes off in a huff.

I'd kind of like to have keyboard input, controller input and graphics output at the same time.

Can anyone help me with the correct incantation that gets me a CoreWindow I can use without important other features stopping working?

This is all C++.
And it's code that works in WinJS.

Comment: Moved the input poll to a different thread than the DirectX render call, and now it renders OK, but the input thread freezes when I call GetAsyncKeyState() so I've now got an even wider range of failure modes to choose from.

Comment: Seems like you have resolved it, did you? If not, please update your issue with what you have resolved and what the new issues you got.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't resolve the problem, just gave me a slightly different take on the existing one. I still can't get keyboard input in my app using GetAsyncKeyState()