# How can I get keyboard input when WebView visible in C++/XAML/UWP App?

Tags: c++, xaml, canvas, webview, uwp

I have a game app that is rendered on a Canvas, with an interface rendered in a WebView.

All the pre-game menus happen in the WebView. When the game starts I switch the WebView to a page with a transparent background so you can see the game Canvas through it, but I can still overlay some interface elements.

This all works fine graphically, and I can see my game clearly with the WebView interface overlayed. I can communicate between the game and the interface quite happily.

The problem I have is getting the WebView to give up the keyboard, so I can use the keys to control the game.

My keyboard listener is triggered on the (theoretically) global event Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown, so it should get keyboard events whatever has the focus.

- I cannot set the focus on the Canvas (and add KeyDown to the Canvas), because it doesn't have a Focus() method.
- I cannot get the WebView to relinquish the keyboard by calling Focus(unfocus). It just doesn't.
- I cannot add KeyDown and KeyUp handlers to the Webview, and pass them on to the Canvas, because WebView doesn't support those methods. (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/web-view)
- I cannot add KeyDown and KeyUp handlers to the common parent of the WebView and Canvas, because the WebView doesn't let the events 'bubble up'.
- I cannot call the low-level keyboard functions from the game in Windows, because the function calls never return. (See [How Can I Call GetAsyncKeyState() in UWP DirectX/XAML App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103819/how-can-i-call-getasynckeystate-in-uwp-directx-xaml-app))
- I cannot use the HTML functions to provide input via JS, because they're too unresponsive for the game.
- I cannot use FocusManager to cycle through the focussable objects, because it only ever chooses the WebView.
- I cannot use WebViewBrush because overlay elements need to animate.

If I hide the WebView everything works fine, the keyboard events are picked up and the game is controllable. Obviously though I can't see the overlayed elements.

Is there some way to let me receive the keyboard events when the WebView is visible?

This is a Win 10/UWP app written in XAML/C++.
Target platform is Win 10 10.0.14393.0/ minimum 10.0.10586.0
Tested on Surface Book running Windows 10 v1703 15063.674

Comment: It seems we can not fire the `KeyDown` event  in `InkCanvas` when the `WebView` cover on it. We should be able to add `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown` event to instead of the `KeyDown` event  in `InkCanvas`.

Comment: Turns out that I am subscribed to Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown already, and it's not coming through when WebView is visible. This is a pain, because Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown is supposed to be called no matter which element has focus. Editing question to make it clearer.

Comment: If there is no other KeyDown  event in your page, you should be able to use `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown` event. When I set MyWebView.Focus(FocusState.Pointer); in the page loaded event, the `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown` event always works.

Comment: OK, there is something very odd happening. To simplify things I've made a completely new project with VS2015 , using the DirectX11/XAML Windows Universal template. This gets a spinning cube.
I've added a Webview to the XAML file, and a CoreWindow.KeyDown listener to the xaml.cpp, with a breakpoint so I can see when it's hit.  When I start the app and press a key, the breakpoint isn't hit. 
If I click in the window, then press a key, the breakpoint isn't hit.  
This seems to be what I'm seeing in my app. 
However! alt-tab away and back again, suddenly breakpoint is hit when I press key.

Comment: Just to confuse things, if I navigate the webview to a new page then I stop getting the keypresses again. But if I alt-tab out and back, they appear. Until I navigate the webview to a new page again, and then they stop.
It seems like the double alt-tab is taking the focus off the webview, and that is allowing the keypresses to come through, but the webview is still visible.  
Now, if only I could get that to happen without alt-tabbing.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to release the focus from the WebView by hiding and then showing it again immediately.

```
webView->Visibility = Visibility::Collapsed;
webView->Visibility = Visibility::Visible;
```

Even if there's nowhere else for the focus to go -
after this operation, `FocusManager::GetFocusedElement()` will return null.

The webview will remain visible, but keyboard events can now be received via `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown`.

Note however that any interaction with the webview (eg. touch, navigation) will cause it to regain focus and you will stop receiving keyboard events.

This isn't a very satisfactory solution, but it sort-of fulfills the requirement to see the webview but also receive keyboard events.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem but managed to fix it with this trick based on Andy's answer:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer
{
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)
};

timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    if (FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() is WebView webView)
    {
        webView.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        webView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
};

timer.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a Webview that must be interactive in our game at all times.
The least ugly workaround that I have found so far is injecting a global event listener into the javascript to hook keyboard input, and relaying this back to the app via notify()

```
function onKeyDown(ev: KeyboardEvent) {

    let wrapper = { keyDown: ev }
    window['external']['notify'](JSON.stringify(wrapper));
}

function onKeyUp(ev: KeyboardEvent) {

    let wrapper = { keyUp: ev }
    window['external']['notify'](JSON.stringify(wrapper));
}


...

        let options: AddEventListenerOptions = { capture: true, passive:true,once:false } 
        document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, options);
        document.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp, options);
```